# How to retrieve image url form Firebase storage for JSON Parsing?

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-storage

I was thinking about making View-pager in android. Which retrieves slider images from a server, so that I can change those slider images at any time. I know for this I have to pass an image URL in JSON format. But I am not understanding how to get those image urls so that I can pass those image URLs in JSON format.

I tried to store an image in Storage of the Firebase. I don't know if this is the right way or not? [I uploaded this image on firebase storage below this image there is a storage location url can i use that storage location url in json?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFK6A.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Yes,You have stored it right.You can use following code to get download url:

Just replace path with your image path e.g `images/6401.jpg`

```
final StorageReference ref = storageRef.child("path");
uploadTask = ref.putFile(file);

Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
    @Override
    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            throw task.getException();
        }

        // Continue with the task to get the download URL
        return ref.getDownloadUrl();
    }
}).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            //Your image url do something with it.
            Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
        } else {
            // Handle failures
            // ...
        }
    }
});
```

Fore more info on this please visit this site here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files

Or

To see complete example you can use this link:
https://github.com/firebase/snippets-android/blob/1c8f86671919fccd43178488fc4799d49f27d786/storage/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/referencecode/storage/StorageActivity.java#L309-L332